# How to launch Chrome Dev Tools device "inspect" programmatically?

Tags: android, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, stetho

I'm working with [Facebook's Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) android plugin and everytime I make a change to my app, the debugger gets detached. Which means everytime I make a change, I have to click inspect, and move to the console tab.

[image]

#### Does anyone know how to launch the "inspect" button programmatically using the terminal or with node-js?

Comment: Probably related: https://crbug.com/642577

Comment: I think it can be done with Screen Scrapping.